# Display 4 numbers for one leaflet marker/point

Tags: leaflet, maps

So, I have weather data that I need to show winds, temperature and dewpoint for one lat/long point.

I am able to show the marker in leaflet as a point but I can not figure out how to draw a point with essentially 4 label's at the 12, 3, 6, and 9 o'clock positions.

My initial thought was to use the marker with DivIcon to create a text marker.  one for each category of each point.  However, this is obviously not the best way as that would mean that I now have 5 points for each point (one for the marker and one for each of the 4 categories).

My next thought, as somewhat already stated, is to create a marker with 4 labels.

1. Is this the best way?  One marker with 4 labels?  If so, how do I code that.
2. Is there something else I'm not thinking of that would be better.

Any help, guidance and/or code would be very helpful.

Other items.  I'm using geoJson files as my data which i have included a sample of.  I have also included a picture of what the outcome should look like.

```
{  
"name": "CurrentCondtions",
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
      {
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "coordinates": [ -63.17, 46.35 ],
    "type": "Point"
  },
  "properties": {
    "DateTimeCurCond": "3/21/2018 11:00:00 AM",
    "Station": "CAHR",
    "Id": "HARRINGTON CDA CS",
    "Temperature": "33",
    "SusWind": "14",
    "GustWind": "",
    "PeakWind": "20",
    "MaxWind": "20",
    "Dewpoint": "19",
    "Identifier": "Point"
  }
}]}
```

[image: sample image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

```
return new L.Marker(latlng,
                                            {
                                                icon: new L.DivIcon(
                                                {
                                                    className: 'baseCurCondClass',
                                                    // html here defines what goes in the div created for each marker
                                                    html: '<div id="curConditionPoint" class="baseCurCondClass" style="width:100px;">'
                                                            + '<div class="row">'
                                                                + '<div class="col-sm-12">'
                                                                    + '<div class="maxWindClass text-center">' + feature.properties.MaxWind + '</div>'
                                                                + '</div>'
                                                            + '</div>'
                                                            + '<div class="row">'
                                                                + '<div class="col-sm-4">'
                                                                    + '<div class="temperatureClass text-right">' + feature.properties.Temperature + '</div>'
                                                                + '</div>'
                                                                + '<div class="col-sm-4">'
                                                                    + '<div>C</div>'
                                                                + '</div>'
                                                                + '<div class="col-sm-4">'
                                                                    + '<div class="dewpointClass text-left">' + feature.properties.Dewpoint + '</div>'
                                                                + '</div>'
                                                            + '</div>'
                                                            + '<div class="row">'
                                                                + '<div class="col-sm-12">'
                                                                    + '<div class="susWindClass text-center">' + feature.properties.SusWind + '</div>'
                                                                + '</div>'
                                                            + '</div>'
                                                        + '</div>',
                                                    // and the marker width and height
                                                    iconSize: null,
                                                    iconAnchor: [50, 50]
                                                })
                                            });
                            }


.susWindClass {         /*bottom*/
color: #003ef7;
}

.maxWindClass {         /*top*/
color: #FF0000;
}

.temperatureClass {     /*left*/
color: #FFFF00;
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
}

.dewpointClass {        /*right*/
color: #D58D14;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
}
```